# using HQL select from joined tables having one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have two classes  and i have one-to-many relationshit between then. these classes are :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp300", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"personId", "empName","last_name"}))
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq",sequenceName="my_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id
    private int Pid;


    private String empName, last_name, position, boss,personId;
    private String birthDate;
    private int salary;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "depId", nullable = false)
    private Department department;
    //setters and getters 
    }
```

and second one :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dep300", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "depName"))
public class Department implements Serializable, Comparable<Department> {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "DEPARTMENTS_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @Id
    private int depId;

    private String depName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Employee> lst = new HashSet<Employee>(0);
    //setters and getters
    }
```

now i am interested in how can i white HQL command to get all employee fields in each department ( passing parameter department name)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Do the following change in the Department class

```
public class Department implements Serializable, Comparable<Department> {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Employee> lst = new HashSet<Employee>(0);
}
```

This will help you fetch all the Employee working, when you fetch the department.

Then add a method to your repository class as follows. I assume you use some form of Spring data CRUD repository to get this work done. 
If not do necessary changes according to your setup.

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT d from Department d where d.depName = :depName")
    Department getDepartmentByName(@Param("depNamename") String depName)
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: there is exception after this changes you wrote . same exception  :                                 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [d.depName], unexpected token [d] [SELECT d from ge.ufc.hibernate.Emps.Department  where d.depName = :depName]

Comment: @Query("SELECT d from Department where d.depName = :depName")

Missing alias "d" so it should be like this:

@Query("SELECT d from Department d where d.depName = :depName")

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to select from Employee class with clause is department. depName=:passingParam

```
from Employee e where e.department.depName = :passingParam;
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for select queries [from ge.ufc.hibernate.Emps.Employee e where e.department.depName=:mname]

Comment: Try with this, it should be have a space between parameter and equal character like this:

from Employee e where e.department.depName = :mname;

or you should fix a specific department name in your query to be sure there is no problem with passing parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Leave everything lazy as it is, otherwise you will introduce joins for other queries when you don't need them.

Use the following query to get a list of employees:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.department.depName = :departmentName
```

Or the following to get a list of departments with their employees fetched:

```
SELECT d FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.lst WHERE d.depName IN (:departmentNames)
```